# How can i change printf("%.2f") in C++

Tags: c++, formatting, number-formatting, cout

How can i change `printf("%.2f")` in C++ so that it will also display upto two decimals 
Using cout

Also for this to change in c++ to have blank space just like in c 
`printf("-6c%14d%20.2f",'A',val1,val2);`
I have declared val1,val2 in double

Comment: See the example code at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision. That should be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried to search it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for change use header file < iomanip >  with setprecision(number of digit to display)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
double a;
cin>>a;
  cout<<setprecision(4)<<a;
return 0;
}
```

for your 2nd question to have blank space just like that in c++ you can simply use this method with setprecision
as your question requires it

```
 cout<<" "<< 'A'<<"\t\t    "<<val1<<"\t\t     "<<setprecision(4)<<val2<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for this ,it was much more helpful and well explained for both questions

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`std::setprecision()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/cpp_setprecisiond.htm) which is used for stream manipulation

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
  float pi = 3.14159;
std::cout<<std::setprecision(3)<<pi;
return 0;
}
```